# How can I access the result of this function on this other function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, keycode

So i have this text input field and I have the **showKeyCode()** function which gets the value from the text input and prints the keycode representation of the pressed key into the console.

```js
function showKeyCode() {
$('#inputfield').keyup(function(e){
   $(this).val(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)); 
   console.log(e.keyCode);
});
}
const r4 = document.querySelector("#inputfield");
r4.addEventListener('input', showKeyCode2);
```

Now i want to get this value and use it at the function below.

```js
 $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which ==  [I WANT TO PUT THE RESULT FROM showKeyCode() HERE] ){
      document.querySelector('#test').click()
      console.log("Clicked");
    }
});
```

Lets summarize what I'm trying to do here. If you are a gamer you must have used the keybinds for example : Press [M] to show minimap. Press [H] to show hud.

Here im trying to make the user customize the keybind by typing it into the text field. The **showKeyCode()** function gets the Character and converts it into a keycode which ill use in the second function.

I couldve typed the keycode directly into the script like this

```js
if (e.which ==  84 ){}
```

but i wanted the user to change it inside the game.

Comment: You can't, at first, `showKeyCode` doesn't seem to return anything, and secondly, the return values of event listeners are ignored (the handler is called from the event queue).

Comment: How can i modify the code to make this happen

Comment: "_You can't_" is you can't ... This looks badly like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the task you're trying to resolve with these event handlers?

Comment: If you play any games , there's this feature example : Press M to show the Map, and you can change that key bind . I'm trying to do the same thing, where  i want the user to choose his own keybind.

Comment: Explain it all in the question itself. See [ask]

Comment: Sorry @tin its hard to understand what you're trying to achieve given the code.
On face value, why not store the value in a variable, then read the value of the variable into your []

Comment: That makes this interesting question, if you'd just put that comment into your question, maybe with a bit of more details.

Comment: Even though i got the answer from @i-am-l , i edited the question in case someone has the same problem and wants a better fix for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically *"You can't"* But there's a hacky and dirty workaround. Global variables.

```
//outside
let value = '';

function showKeyCode() {
  $('#inputfield').keyup(function(e){
     $(this).val(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)); 
     value = e.keyCode;
  });
}


$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which ==  [value] ){
      document.querySelector('#test').click()
      console.log("Clicked");
    }
});
```

This should work if `sowKeyCode` was called before a keydown was made

Now, **I DO NOT RECCOMMEND** using global variables but sometimes its the only way on the approach, perhaps you can use a different method like putting this inside a `class` or using other libraries that are great with state tracking.

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly. I was in doubt about using global variables but it does the job for the moment.